# How to customize default document name(Document 1) in MSWord?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, word-automation

I know that, we can change the MS Word Application caption, but I am trying to customize the Document name... can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, it's not possible. This is hard-coded in the Word application and there is no option or way to change it. The only way to change the document name is to SAVE AS.